# Can units in neural hidden layer capture same feature?

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, data-science

In neural network, there are 3 main parts defined as input layer, hidden layer and output layer. We provide same input for hidden layer, so can we get same units in hidden layer. For example, we are giving dogs pictures as input, and our hidden layers are capturing body parts of dog. I want to know, is their any chance that 2 units of hidden layer capture same body part like eye.

I know that inputs are same but we initialize weights differently. Hence, chances of this happening is low. But, I am curious that is their any possibility of happening this, can to units of hidden layers dependent on each other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theoretically speaking, it is possible that two or more units pick up on the same feature of the input; however, this should not happen in practice if the network is well designed. Random initialization is a way, for example, to alleviate this problem.

Putting it in terms of effects on loss function, if one neuron learns a specific feature, the optimizer will return nothing for updating the weights of another neuron that leans the same feature because it will not minimize the overall loss function. This can be justified by the fact that optimizer would not learn a feature twice, and if this happens (which *normally* doesn't happen in a well-designed network), then learning it another time will not minimize the cost function.

With all the explanations above, there is no guarantee that the case you mentioned will not happen.